# How to search text messages

Tags: search, sms

I remember getting a text a long time ago but I text tons with this person so there are too many sms messages to look through. How do I search my text messages for a specific phrase?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no such mechanism for searching text msg. But, you can refine the msgs and call by date. Go into Contacts, select the intended person and then swipe left to **history**. This might help you a little bit in refining and sorting the conversations by date.